# Cannot update Intel G31/G33 Graphics Controller

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel

My last computer ended with a burning smell when I was trying to install more memory. My Samsung SSD is up-to-date with 18.04 Ubuntu. I put it into another used computer which has a G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller. Ubuntu is working fine, except that it hangs up at the splash screen during boot-up, and I need to boot-up every time from the GRUB menu. Also the screen resolution is not right. The terminal says "unable to get EDID for xrandr-default: unable to get EDID for output". Intel no longer supports the G33/G31 drivers for Ubuntu. Regarding updates for this driver, their website says "Users may be unable to use the native resolution of some displays when using Intel chipset graphics." "The display EDID is not read properly when connecting to a subset of Digital Flat Panel (DFP) displays." "Intel has released this driver to specifically address this issue   .   .   ." Unfortunately, the updated driver is only for Windows. I bought the computer for $200 and have spent at least 40 hours trying to find answers. Did I waste my time and money? Can I fix it, or should I just buy a new computer? There may be other issues that I do not know about, but the computer seems to work fine, except the graphics are not right. If I run lshw in the terminal, it says "*-display UNCLAIMED". When I opened "Activities" and typed in "Displays", the resolution I needed(1280 X 1024) was not listed. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

PARTIAL SUCCESS: I opened "Activities", typed in "Displays", clicked on "Color", clicked on "Default Monitor", clicked on "Add Profile" at the bottom of the menu. On the drop-down list was Samsung SyncMaster. And I just happened to have an older Samsung SyncMaster monitor. I put a checkmark on that option. And I was able to get that monitor to work in the right resolution (1280 X 1024). :)   The 1280 X 1024 option even showed up in the "Displays" menu :)  The first monitor still will not start with the right resolution, but if I start the computer with the Samsung monitor, then switch the cable to the other monitor, it will also work in the right resolution. However, I still must boot-up the computer from the recovery menu in GRUB. It's after midnight. I'm going home.